# Cut and paste in linux Interruption

Tags: linux, paste, cut

I want to clarify about cut and paste in linux. I was cut and pasting files from one folder to another. The system just stopped working and cut and paste operation interrupted in the middle. So some files transferred but some didn't. I have a question that did "Transferred files" are complete and won't be missing sub files?

Answer (score 1):

In any OS, `Linux/Windows`, a cut paste is similar to copy paste and deleting the source file. So, you will be left with a copy of file either in source or destination path.

So you will have to check where the file is currently present. If it is in Source path, the file was not transferred, if its in destination, transfer is complete. You might find some files which are present in both locations. For them delete the destination file and again transfer them from source.

Comment: So in other words, those files which are only in destination or source folder at a time, they are not damage. But those files which are both in destination and source folder, then the same files in the destination folder are damage whereas same files in the source folder are not damage?

Comment: Secondally, in the cut and paste operation in linux, do the files transfer one after another or they transfer in parallel fashion and in small batches?

Comment: Its normally one after another. If you have started multiple transfer processes, then it will transfer in parallel.